# Prove $e^{n+2011}<\sum_{k=2012}^n2^k\binom{n}{k}<\pi^{n-2013}$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, proof-verification

I need to prove that $\exists N\in\mathbb{N} \,\,s.t. \,\,\forall n>N:$ $$e^{n+2011}<\sum_{k=2012}^n2^k\binom{n}{k}<\pi^{n-2013}$$
Will appreciate a hint. I'm guessing I need to use asymptotic notations... but don't really know how.

Comment: Edited, I copied it wrong :\

Answer (score 1):

Hint: relate middle term to binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Strong hint 1: what is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} 2^k 1^{n-k}$ ?

Hint 2: the numbers $2011$, $2012$, $2013$ are red herrings.